# What is the explanation for the water scene?

Tags: inside

At some part of the game when you venture to the underwater parts of the facility

> you get dragged down by a monster and instead of dying you become capable of underwater breathing. Can anyone explain this? How come the main character does not die but starts breathing underwater?

Answer (score 2):

I thought they did that to add to the general creepiness, but also to enable

> the upside-down water mechanic.

I don't think you could make it through those sections without

> being able to last indefinitely underwater without dying.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the game's hints that

> the boy is being mind controlled the entire time. When you mind control others they appear to be able to continue through conditions that would normally kill, like long falls and prolonged periods underwater. Since the boy "survives" drowning, the game is telling us that he is actually being controlled.

I wrote more about the other hints the game gives you for this in [my explanation of the game's ending](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/321633/197244).

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely in the scene, [the boy *actually drowns*](https://youtu.be/ylr2RJ0eYNg?t=12m19s). Then, just a bit later, you'll also notice [*something* gets attached to him](https://youtu.be/ylr2RJ0eYNg?t=12m43s) — when playing through this the first time, I assumed that whatever got attached to him somehow gave him the ability to breathe under water (in fact, I was pressing the action button all the time, and thought *I*'d saved the boy, ah :P ).

The thing that gets attached to the boy also has a yellow light, much like the mind control helmets you need to put on to solve some puzzles. So I thought that if a yellow-lit helmet can give you mind control powers, why can't a yellow-lit *something* that gets attached to your chest bring you back to life *and* give you under water breathing capabilities?

Comment: I wonder if it might resemble the slug, the kind you pull out of a pig's butt...

Comment: The slug doesn't produce any sort of light, though (unless I'm misremembering?). Furthermore, the pig with the slug kinda went berserk, and we are still able to keep the boy under control, so I'd say it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: Or maybe the boy died there and the yellow thing just controls the corpse?

Comment: Ooh, yes! Entirely possible!